# docker daemon start using ansible

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible

I am working on ansible script for **start docker damon , docker container, docker exec**  After start docker container with in the docker container i need to start some services.

I have installed docker engine , configured and working with some docker container in remote machines. i have used to start docker daemon with specific path, because i need to store my volumes and containers with in path.

```
 $docker daemon -g /test/docker
```

My issue is **when start the docker daemon its started, but not go to next process.** via ansible. still running docker daemon.

```
  ---
  - hosts: webservers
    remote_user: root

   # Apache Subversion   dnf -y install python-pip

    tasks:

      - name: Start Docker Deamon
        shell: docker -d -g /test/docker 
        become: yes
        become_user: root

      - name: Start testing docker machine
        command: docker start testing
        async: True
        poll: 0
```

I follow async to start the [process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994021/ansible-start-python-flask-script-in-new-terminal-window) ,but its not working for me ,

Suggest me After start docker daemon, How to run next process.

Answer (score 9):

In order to start the docker daemon you should use the ansible [service module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html):

```
- name: Ensure docker deamon is running
  service:
    name: docker
    state: started
  become: true
```

any docker daemon customisation should be placed in **/etc/docker/daemon.json** as described in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/). in your case the file would look like:

```
{
   "graph": "/test/docker"
}
```

In order to interact with containers, use the ansible [docker_container module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html):

```
- name: Ensure My docker container is running
  docker_container:
    name: testing
    image: busybox
    state: started
  become: true
```

Try to avoid doing anything in ansible using the shell module, since it can cause headaches down the line.

Comment: I used the service module to start docker demon but sometimes, I get error when trying to run a "docker" command right after this.  "Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?\n\nIf it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable."

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan-Ul-Haq check your docker configuration and/or systemd unit files. there is a misconfiguration there for `host`

Answer (score 3):

You can also start Docker and other services automatically when booting the machine. For that you can use the `systemd` module in Ansible like this:

```
- name: Enable docker.service
  systemd:
    name: docker.service
    daemon_reload: true
    enabled: true

- name: Enable containerd.service
  systemd:
    name: containerd.service
    daemon_reload: true
    enabled: true
```

Reference: [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html)